# How does Shumway convert Flash to HTML5?

Tags: html, flash, renderer

Mozilla's [Shumway](https://github.com/mozilla/shumway) project appears to play SWFs without requiring a Flash player to be installed:

> Shumway is an HTML5 technology experiment that explores building a
>   faithful and efficient renderer for the SWF file format without native
>   code assistance.

I'm looking at the source of their [racing demo](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/examples/racing/) and can only see a link to a SWF and no JS.

How are they displaying this SWF without any Flash plugin being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shumway loads, parses and executes SWF with JS, and uses HTML5 `<canvas>` to render it.

You can see a bit better what's going on behind the scenes when you open the SWF in the [Shumway Inspector](http://www.areweflashyet.com/shumway/examples/inspector/inspector.html). Direct link for the racing game: http://www.areweflashyet.com/shumway/examples/inspector/inspector.html?rfile=../racing/race.swf

Comment: Thanks @Claus, that inspector is really impressive and will help to dive deeper into the bowels of Shumwell!